# Javascript - Match Regex for multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a regex like that:

```
[Intro]

E|------|---4-|
B|--3h5-|-----|
C|------|-----|
D|------|---3-|
G|-1----|-----|
E|------|--0--|
```

to get me those groups:

```
Group1: Intro
Group2: E
Group3: ------|---4-|
Group4: B
Group5: --3h5-|-----|
Group6: C
Group7: ------|-----|
etc until the last line
```

There are always six lines.
Now, I got to a point where this pattern:

```
((?:\w|\s|b|#|m){1,2})\|((?:(?:\d|\w|-|\/|^|~|\\|\(|\))+\|)+)
```

return me this match for such string:

```
Match1:
Group1: E
Group2: ------|---4-|
Match2:
Group1: B
Group2: --3h5-|-----|

etc until last line
```

My question is, how can I match the regex to match only exactly six line with one line break between each line (Maybe using the pattern I wrote and add line break at start or end or something)

And also how to get the [Intro] tag which is two linebreak away from the six lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is :-

- Split the string first by newline
- Remove all the falsy values
- map over array and replace undesired characters
- flatten the array

```js
let str = `[Intro]

E|------|---4-|
B|--3h5-|-----|
C|------|-----|
D|------|---3-|
G|-1----|-----|
E|------|--0--|`

let final = str.split('\n')
               .filter(Boolean)
               .map(v=> v.replace(/[\]\[]/g,'').match(/^[^|]+\||.+/g))
               .flat()

console.log(final)
```